# cannot invoke a non-delegate type

Tags: c#, invoke

I am trying to use threading  and that includes a GUI controller, so I needed to invoke that controller but I have this problem- I cannot invoke a non-delegate type in this part of the code

```
if (toolStripTextBox1.Text != "")
{
    if (RT[j].tabvalue.ToString() == tabControl1.Invoke(() =>
                                       { tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name; }))
    {
        RT[j].RitchT.Text = getH.getHtmlCode(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

while this is working on the other hand

```
tabControl1.Invoke(
    () => { tabControl1.TabPages[R.RitchT.Name].Controls.Add(R.RitchT);
});
```

This is the invoke class

```
 public static class ControlExtensions
 {
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(action), null);
        else
            action.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What you want to achieve by this line - `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name`?

Comment: just returning that tab name and using it to check something in an if statement

Comment: That won't compile. You should instead use `Func<string>` as specified by Hans Passant in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
  tabControl1.Invoke(() => { tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name; })
```

Yes, that's not legal syntax.  The Control.BeginInvoke() method takes a Delegate as its first argument.  A lambda expression doesn't convert implicitly to Delegate, you have to help.  Fix:

```
  tabControl1.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => { return tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name; }))
```

You'll have more trouble, you cannot assign the Text property of a RichTextBox in a worker thread, you'll have to use BeginInvoke() there as well.  You'll get away with reading the Text properties but it is rather a bad idea, they may change while the worker thread is running and the user keeps operating the UI.  You really want to favor a BackgroundWorker or Task, collect the data you need for the worker before you start it, update the UI with the results of the worker after it is done.

Comment: Also delegate method body isn't correct. It won't compile either.

Comment: Thanks you v much that worked Fine .. and yeah i have the problem that ur talking about now.. i will try and read more on this subject thanks again